# How can we  use a condition statement in email template?

Tags: salesforce

I have one issue related to visualforce email template please help me out.
I am using below code to hide the tr:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Airline_Conf_s__r}">
 <tr style="{!IF(!cx.Include_in_Confirmation__c == true,"display:none!important; ","")}">
<td>
<apex:outputText value="{!cx.Airlines_Url__c}" escape="false" /> 
</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>

but i need it to done without inline style .how can it possible.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the "rendered" attribute of apex:outputtext, like this

```
<apex:outputText rendered = "{cx.Include_in_Confirmation__c}" value="{!cx.Airlines_Url__c}" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using an apex:outputPanel tag and using the rendered property:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Airline_Conf_s__r}">
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!cx.Include_in_Confirmation__c == true}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText value="{!cx.Airlines_Url__c}" escape="false" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Note that the layout attribute is set to "none" this will effectively tell VF not to render a tag but you will get the benefits of being able to dynamically render the TR tag as the repeater loops.